# UISearchController search bar misplaced when UISplitViewController mode is all visible

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

My root view controller is a `UISplitViewController` with `preferredDisplayMode` is `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible`. In detail view controller, I have a `UISearchController`, but I don't have a `UITableView` to attach the search bar, so I placed a `UIView` inside the view and add search bar into it:

```
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

// This is the view to contain search bar
_searchView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[_searchView addSubview:_searchController.searchBar];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
```

**UPDATE:** This also happened with `UISearchBar` set to `tableView.tableHeaderView`, not only when contained in a `UIView`.

This is what it looks like at first (I cropped the height of the image):

[image]

But when the search controller is active, the search bar frame's `origin.x` is misplaced to the right, exactly equals to width of master view controller:

[image]

When split view controller is in `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden` mode, that won't happen, search bar is displayed completely normal:

[image]

So is that a bug of `UISplitViewController`? Currently I fix that with this ugly way, reset `origin.x` of search bar, it's kinda glitchy:

```
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    searchController.searchBar.superview.clipsToBounds = NO;

    if (self.splitViewController.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible) {
        searchController.searchBar.frame = ({
            CGRect frame = searchController.searchBar.frame;
            frame.origin.x -= self.splitViewController.primaryColumnWidth;
            frame;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How you found any other solution ? I'm having the same bug on iOS 10.3

Comment: did you find a better solution for this, I am facing the same issue when I add search bar to MasterViewController itself, and change the orientation.

Answer (score 2):

This was giving me tons of trouble. My app worked on everything but iPads because of the search bar being misplaced in the SplitView. I finally came across someone who posted the solution. Add this to the end of viewDidLoad() for your table view:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

source: [searchBar from UISearchController not showing correctly on split view on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171704/searchbar-from-uisearchcontroller-not-showing-correctly-on-split-view-on-ipad)